# If mass increases as velocity increases, does gravity increase as well?

Tags: gravity, mass, velocity, relativity

The way I understand it, velocity and mass are tied together with relativity.

As I increase in velocity, I increase my mass until my mass is so great that it would take more energy than the entire universe to accelerate me that last .1% to light speed.

So, as I accelerate and increase my mass, would this also increase the amount of gravity I generate? After a certain point, would I be generating so much gravity that I would collapse in on myself?

Comment: When you try to model mass as increasing then you incorrectly predict how hard it is accelerate in a direction orthogonal to your existing motion. So modern physicists don't do that. They instead use correct equations to relate mass, momentum, velocity, and energy. And also, mass isn't the source of gravity. Energy density, momentum density, energy flux, pressure, and stress are the sources. And despite the word source, it is not right to think gravity is a thing generated by an object. Sources connect different vacuum solutions together.